# Display inline-flex preventing float right from working on span elements

Tags: html, css, display

mocked up an example of my issue (simplified) in this codepen: https://jsfiddle.net/bhuaL0vf/12/

I'm basically unsure of what styles on the `styled-link` are preventing the `open-text` from floating right to the end of the row - so that it sits right at the end as opposed to cosied up-beside it. I've re-created this elsewhere with these styles however inline-flex is not necessary there so I am assuming it is to do with that.

TEMPLATE:

```
<li class="styled-link">
  <span class="open-text">Open</span>
  List item one
</li>
```

STYLES:

```
 .styled-link {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #63666a;
  }
  
  .open-text {
    float: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 35px;
  }
```

Apologies if I'm missing something really obvious, a little unfamiliar with `inline-flex`.

Comment: `inline-flex` is making your `li` a flex container, the `float` property is ignored in a flex container.

Comment: use inline-block instead

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `inline-flex` with `flex` and justify the flex items using `justify-content` property to achieve the desired alignment as per your needs.

For example:

```
 .styled-link {
    display: flex; /* Replaced inline-flex to flex /*
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #63666a;
    justify-content: space-between; /* Add space between flex items */
  }
  /* Removed float */
  .open-text {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 35px;
  }
```